# Infinite sequence 12345678910111213

Tags: algorithm, numbers, sequence, infinite

Given an infinite sequence of numbers:

12345678910111213141516..... and so on. I have to find a first position of an input string. Like this:

> ```
> 1234   gives 1   
> 13     gives 16  
> 111    gives 12
> ```

Anyone already figured out an algorithm for such question?

Comment: show what have you tried, its not a place to ask for your homework

Comment: Voting to close as too-broad.

Comment: Read up on the "trie" data structure

Comment: The obvious way is just to walk all the way through it, generating the numbers as you go, and stop when you find it. You can take some shortcuts, I'll leave them as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @Harold: the brute force solution will be exponential in the length of the string...

Comment: @YvesDaoust sure. I'm not advocating it as the best way. It is the most obvious way though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**:

If you know that the input string starts on a whole number, you can check that hypothesis quickly by trying all prefixes. For instance, take **21521**.

**2** can not be right as it continues as 2 *3 4*...

**21** can not be right as it continues as 21 *22 23*...

**215** is fine as it continues as **215 21**6...

It is also possible that the string does not start on a whole number, so you can try the suffixes as starting on a whole number, and check the preceding digits.

2  **1521** can be **152 1**53..., but this is preceded by 15 *1*,

21  **512** can be **512** 513..., but this is preceded by 5 *11*,

215  **12** can be **1 2** 3..., but this is preceded by... nothing,

2151  **2** can be **2** 3..., but this is not preceded by enough digits.

Remains to find the index after you identified the match. You will have to accumulate the counts of the single digits numbers, the two digits numbers...

Also need to check that no possibility is missed.

---

At first sight, this process takes time `O(N³)` where `N` is the length of the string, whatever its position.